# python way to get mounted filesystems

Tags: python, python-2.6

This is how I manage to enumerate mounted filesystems in python:

```
for line in open("/etc/mtab"):
    mount_point = line.split()[1]
    if mount_point.startswith('/foo/bar'):
        ...
```

Is there a better, cleaner or simpler way? I haven't found anything in the standard modules (os, stat, statvfs, etc).

Comment: You might want to list comprehension them

Comment: There are cases when a mounted file system doesn't end up in `/etc/mtab`. You can [use `/proc/mounts` instead](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24230).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to collect the result into a list comprehension instead of a for loop.

Example for the code you've provided:

```
collection = [line.split()[1] for line in open("/etc/mtab")
              if line.split()[1].startswith('/foo/bar')]
```

This creates a list of all the mount_point which start with '/foo/bar' even faster

If you just want to iterate on them, then use a generator expression instead:

```
collection = (line.split()[1] for line in open("/etc/mtab")
              if line.split()[1].startswith('/foo/bar'))
```